# Gradient equality with tensor product

Tags: real-analysis

I have this question :

Why do we have this equality, and how to prove it

$$\nabla\nabla(|u|^5u)=5|u|^3\nabla u\otimes \nabla u+5|u|^5\nabla\nabla u$$

where $u$ is a smooth function defined on an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Thank you very much

Comment: The reason nobody is helping you is because you have not mentioned any attempts you have made to do the problem.

Comment: i found this equality in a demonstration of a problem so what i have to put in addition @ Sir Jective